# Azure Computer Vision API - OCR Image to Text in tabular format

Tags: rpa, uipath

I am using RPA Uipath tool...Can anyone give some idea how to extract the table data from an image with the tabular structure I tried using Microsoft vision using Read text but it returns accurate data but in a single column all the values are coming instead of a tabular format? As my image contains a table structure.

[image: Table]

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Computer Vision API gives result in JSON/Text format. You can create an array out of it and then transform it to a datatable.

Comment: Hey..Thanks actually my data is coming as text format..so can you give some example how to achieve it. I want to convert that in datatable.

Comment: I have uploaded code here with the same text
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/d1af0ce5fb958a0b8751b6e9f072603d20190806124501/b1f809848c86e24f4c43725308b0c6c120190806124501/980f0e